# Twitter bootstrap btn-group-vertical with margin in between the buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there an easy way to add some margin between the twitter bootstrap btn-group-vertical buttons, and to make them all have rounded corners?

My first attempt was to just add some margin between them, using css, but then I saw that, except for the first and last one, none of them had rounded corners, so instead of "playing on", I hope there is a "decent" way to accomplish this...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is the easiest way to do that.

**CSS**

```
.btn-group-vertical > button{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-radius:10px !important;
}
```

#### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eydreeyawn/nyfLw4h8/)

Comment: @DylanDelobel It used to work. It is now updated and working again.

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 5.1 you can now use the gap utilities to achieve this:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/#gap

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical gap-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Button</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Button</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Button</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Button</button>
</div>
```